# Here's an ancient puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

Two market women were selling their apples, one at three for a penny and the other at two for a penny. One day they were both called away when each had thirty apples unsold: these they handed to a friend to sell at five for 2¢. It will be seen that if they had sold their apples separately they would have fetched 25¢, but when they were sold together they fetched only 24¢.

"Now," people ask, "what in the world has become of that missing penny?" because, it is said, three for 1¢ is surely exactly the same as five for 2¢.

Can you explain the little mystery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stock

> Woman A: 30 apples (originally sold at two for a penny)
> Woman B: 30 apples (originally sold at three for a penny)

Indeed, if each sold their apples individually, there be a total income of 25 cents (Woman A = 30/2 = 15 cents; Woman B = 30/3 = 10 cents)

It would seem that this is the same result you get by combining the stock and selling five for two pennies. However:

> Consider that each woman contributes apples in sets according to their original price (Woman A contributes sets of 2 apples, and Woman B contributed sets of 3 apples). Woman B is actually contributing one extra apple to each sale. Thus, once 10 sets of five apples are sold (yielding 20 cents), Woman B is out of apples. At this point, Woman B has sold 30 apples and has earned her expected 10 cents (a penny per three apples) and Woman A has sold 20 apples and has earned 10 cents (a penny per two apples).
>
>  There remain 10 apples from Woman A. At two cents per five apples, this brings in five additional pennies, thus yielding a total of 25 cents.

Comment: Not the way I solved the problem but you're still right.....I think.